# Best way to implement an xpath-like configuration system

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to come up with the best way to handle configuration in an application. At first i just used SimpleXML and put the code in a singleton.

I've decided to try to create a way to query the configuration with something like `$config->getConfig('/module/name');`

Do you have to use xpath to do this or is there any other method that is faster/easier to use? I know Magento uses this scheme but with a custom xpath-like syntax.

Feel free to suggest different schemes as long as it is based on XML.

SimpleXML is a nice approach however i feel the need to wrap something around it as the return values are almost always objects where I want a string value.

Could someone explain how to wrap the xpath call to return a string value if the query returns a value, or an object if the query has multiple children?

```
        $xml = $this->xml->xpath($path);
```

How do you detect if the node returned is a leaf node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend trying [SimpleXml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) as it allows you to write regular PHP to query the XML instead of XPath. If using XPath is a requirement, you can [execute XPath expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) with it as well, but being able to write `$config->module->name` is quite nice, imho.

Comment: SimpleXML is not ruled out, and SimpleXML has an xpath() method. However this is a simple method and i'm trying to figure out if there are better methods around.

Comment: I'm not sure how anything can be much simpler, but good luck in your search anyway. :)

Comment: I ended up using SimpleXML with the xpath() method wrapped in a singleton class with additional logic. All in all, it works pretty good. I can return string or SimpleXML objects, this supports the caching of configuration fragments that i often need.